# SQL insert into, deleting duplicate rows that have some matching info and same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, duplicates, distinct

SCENARIO: I have a master file of customer orders. I need to import some of the columns into the customers table(name, address, etc) and auto-create a customer ID. Then import the rest of the columns from the master file into the orders table(date, agent ID,  joining with the newly created customer ID).
The process works fine except for...

MY PROBLEM IS: There are some rows that are entered twice that have minor differences.
 For example:

```
       (name, phone, address, subscription number)
ROW 1: "John, Smith, 3232112111, 123 2nd St #4, 5shdm67h5" 
ROW 2: "JOHN, SMITH, 13232112111, 123 Second Street Apt. 4, 5shdm67h5".
```

The last value of each row is their "subscription number" which is the unique key. The customer is obviously the same, but the two entries have the values for name, phone, and address entered differently. Using distinct, it is creating two customer IDs for each row of John Smith.

I need DISTINCT to be based only on subscription number and ignore the other columns completely. Every time I try, it only inserts duplicate customers for the customers that were entered with mismatched addresses, phone numbers, etc. So then when inserted into orders, it creates a list of the same orders twice for each of the customer numbers for technically the same customer.

Have tried DISTINCT, where not exists, and ROW_NUMBER in a few different combinations, but I either get the wrong number of customers/orders, or an error for incorrect syntax.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, NumberOfOrders)  
AS  
(  
    SELECT SalesPersonID, NumberOfOrders,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SalesPersonID)  NN
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader  
)  
DELETE FROM Sales_CTE WHERE NN > 1
```

Comment: This is a good answer.  I prefer `select *` for the CTE rather than selecting particular columns, because the intent is to delete the *entire* row.

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you provide query which is inserting this record. Because avoiding duplicate entries is all you need.

And how you are differentiating these 2 records are of same person or 2 different person.

If this is on behalf of `subscription number`. Then you should try to find distinct record on basis of `subscription number` and fill `TOP 1` record in your table

```
  insert into [newtable] ( col1, col2, col3, col4 )
  select Top 1 col1, col2, col3, col4 from [sourcetable] where [subscription number]=@yourvalue
```